# ¿Como puedo eliminar todos los puntos excepto el último de un string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

necesito poder eliminar todos los puntos de un string excepto el último.

Por ejemplo: la oración

> Hol.a. Mun.do

debería quedar

> Hola Mun.do

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes realizarlo de la siguiente forma con regular expressions.

```
import re;
newText = re.sub('\.(?=[^.]*\.)','','Hol.a. Mun.do');
print(newText); #Hola Mun.do
```

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo una manera, a ver si te sirve. Aun así, comentarte que deberías mostrar lo que has hecho, y donde te equivocas cuando hagas una pregunta para que así se te pueda corregir el error y poder aprender.

```
# Tenemos la frase en una variable
frase = 'Hol.a. Mun.do'

# La dividimos según sus puntos
puntos = frase.split('.')
print(puntos)

# Ahora vamos a recorrer la lista que se ha generado con la frase a pedazos, pero como lo que buscas es obviar el último punto, pues hacemos una iteración menos.
nueva_frase = ''
for p in range(len(puntos)-1):
    print(puntos[p])
    nueva_frase = nueva_frase + puntos[p]

# Por último añadimos el punto de nuevo y el último trozo que quedaba.
print(nueva_frase + '.' + puntos[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui te va una posible solución:

```py
def eliminar_puntos(string):
    partes = string.split('.')
    new_string = ""
    for i in range(len(partes)):
        if i == len(partes) - 1:
            new_string += '.'
        new_string += partes[i]
    return new_string


print(eliminar_puntos("Hol.a. Mun.do"))
```